# How should I allow a user to input a number where not all numbers are valid?

Tags: gui-design, input-fields, input

I have an application where users need to configure certain machine settings.  One of these settings is an integer percentage value, from 1-100.  Unfortunately, for historical reasons, we're not actually able to support all values from 1-100, so the range of options actually has all sorts of weird "holes" in it, so it looks a bit more like this:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, *, 6, *, 8, *, 12, *, 16, 17, 18
```

The holes aren't regularly spaced, so we can't shrink the input by only giving the users the options 1-50, or tell them to only put in even numbers, or something clever like that.

Our current method is to use a normal number input, and simply highlight invalid numbers.  This makes it easy for a user to see that their selection is wrong, but it's hard to see (a) *why* it's wrong, and (b) what a correct number might look like.

This leads me to my question: what input element is best suited to helping a user choose a valid number in a situation where not all numbers are valid (but a finite number of numbers *are* valid)?

So far, we've thought about:

- A conventional dropdown

  - There's still ~50 numbers to choose from, that's a lot of dropdown options.  It also feels a bit weird to use a dropdown for a number.
- A "datepicker"-type component

  - The user can type in their number (w/ validation) or select a valid number from a list of numbers shown in a pop-up below the input.
  - This would end up looking essentially like a grid of numbers - is that too much like a datepicker?
- Steppers

  - ~50 numbers is probably too many to choose from easily with steppers, *but* once a number has been set, most adjustments are probably slightly up and slightly down.

Comment: Side question: I'd love to hear more about these historical reasons why there are certain numbers not allowed. I could understand if the values had to be divisible by 2/4/5 or something but I'm curious what the limitations are.

Comment: Why not just a grid of valid numbers always visible showing selected as well as possible values (somewhat like the latter part of your second option). Is it really needed to have a regular input visible at all? User needs to know all possible values and selected value as well as stop him from filling an invalid value - this addresses all three that too in a single click, no?

Comment: Are these values and gaps something you'd expect to be familiar to people using the application? Is there a name for the set of valid numbers?

Comment: Note that a conventional dropdown still allows the users to use the keyboard to select a value. If the value they type is in the list of options, it will automatically be selected. It isn't as cumbersome  to use in this case as you might think.

Comment: Why not just hide this from the user and get the nearest number on the backend?

Comment: @scunliffe: We have some old machines that can only handle a certain number of configuration options before they run out of memory.  There are also two other settings, each with ~5 options, and if we included the full 5 * 5 * 100 = 2500 combinations, we'd hit the memory limit.  Hence, we pick the most commonly-used setting combinations and only allow those.

It's definitely a weird problem!  There are better fixes, but they are more difficult and involve replacing expensive equipment - getting me to figure out this solution is a cheaper option...  ;)

Comment: @Ave looks to be thinking on similar lines to me. Is it absolutely vital that the user picks one of your valid values, or would it be acceptable to "fudge" the user's input? If the user picks 5, then you can show them the number 5 and assure them that 5 is the value you're using, but behind the scenes you can just use 4 and hope nobody notices. If this were a volume control on your website's video player, that would be fine. If this were the control panel of a nuclear reactor, perhaps less so.

Comment: Do the actual numbers matter? For example, 5 is an invalid number. Will a user ever actually be thinking "I need a 5" and then try to input it? What I'm getting at is the possibility of you translating the actual numbers passed to the program to a different 'user facing' scale' so if you had a total of 80 valid numbers you just present a scale or slider to select 1-80 and then translate (5 selected = 6 sent to the program).

Comment: What was the previous UX for configuring the setting? A physical dial/knob? Configuring jumpers on a board? Punching holes in a punch card?

Comment: What I want to know is how this question got more votes and 10 times more views (8K!) than all the other most recentUX questions put together!? What's the magic formula? It doesn't seem like a common situation.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The user is entering a number. That some values are invalid for technical reasons does not change the nature of the user interaction. I would go with an option that is the most natural to enter a number 
Perhaps keep a regular number field, but when the user finishes their input, nudge the number to the closest valid option with a minor message to go with it?

[image]

Comment: The information about 18 and 12-14-19 it's good idea :-) , but arrows is unnecessary, if i have 2 i need to click 80 times to get 82?

Comment: These arrows are just the default UI of the `<input type=number>` in my browser. I can type in a number, but I can also use the mouse to increment. I don’t think the arrows matter much for the answer, but there’s some value in being able to click through similar values.

Comment: Yes of course, it's not a problem, just default setting.

Comment: For starters, "other related valid values" doesn't make a lot of sense. What makes these values "related" to the one I typed? Also, I really don't like automatically *changing* the user's input. I would prefer that my input be left alone exactly as I entered it, and then the suggestion text to the side could say something like, "14 is not a valid input [because ...]; did you mean 12 or 16?"

Comment: "nearby" would be better than "related".

Comment: Note, in such case arrows should not mean "+1" and "-1", but "next valid value" and "previous valid value". Otherwise on some numbers they won't work, as the number will get adjusted right back.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful!  I agree with @CodyGray that automatically changing the input probably isn't the best way to go, but the idea of showing the neighbouring values is helpful.  We can also probably augment the standard number picker interactions so that "next number" and "previous number" automatically skip the invalid ones.

Comment: I agree with Cody Gray - since it is sometimes hard to guess if the entered number is complete, I would not adjust the input field at all, but display the adjusted value beneath it as you type. Otherwise the change could appear on blur - but if the user presses a submit button, the button will activate before the blur-event and the user will not see the adjusted value before submitting it. - so always update the information live as the user is typing, without changing the input field.

Comment: I disagree with @Denis, I think the arrows are the most important part, assuming they move between allowed values and not +/- 1.  Otherwise how am I supposed to know what my options are?

Comment: Is it necessary to display other nearby values? Presumably, if the user wants a different nearby value, they will use the arrows.

Comment: I think this over thinks it. And would suggest that emulating something like a US State input is what falls closest. You let them type in the digits, but also show the drop down of possible options. If they type something invalid, then you tell them it’s invalid.

Comment: Small note: In constrast to a drop-down menu, this needs Javascript or a roundtrip for server-side validation, so this will possibly work less good, e.g., for users with screen readers, that need to use trial and error until the server returns an "ok".

Comment: I actually really dislike this. I find it extremely confusing to offer a free number input field with this verbose explanation of input being automatically adjusted. I think the slider answer provided gets across the valid numbers without needing to use words, and it's obvious what the UI is doing when it snaps to a tick. It's a more complicated implementation but it's at least an order of magnitude better than a free number field

Comment: If the precision of the input is necessary, the slider makes it really frustrating to pick between similar values. Choosing which to use is now dependent on the use case. For instance, if I want the machine to pack me a 100g of coffee, it’s much better to type in 100 and see it update to 98. If I want a more exploratory approach, then the slider is preferred.

Answer (score 62):

I think a horizontal slider with:

- Graduations (tick marks) showing the possible values
- A handle with a triangle end pointing to those tick marks
- Snapping to the closest possible value when you drop the handle
- A feedback of the actual value
- Of course, the ability to manipulate with the keyboard
- Optionally, the ability to use arrows or +/- to move to the next/previous allowed value
- Optionally, a direct input field, with the value being rounded to the closest valid one as soon as fous is lost

would provide the clearest visual indication of the possibilities.

Here's a quick possible example (strongly inspired by the [macOS liner slider with tick marks](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/selectors/sliders/)):

[image]

(I got tired of adding further tick marks)
If you have arrows or +/- or if you want direct input, it would probably be better for the value to be outside of the handle, of course.

Comment: This, if the property is a representation of an analogue quantity (volume? brightness?)  with arbitrary strange digitization constraints. Add a comment explaining that the slider will be snapped to the nearest value which the hardware  is capable of accepting, as tick-marked, to avoid bug reports about not being able to set X to 15.

Comment: For the cases of brightness and volume mentioned by @nigel222, both of those are actually logarithmic in humans, so it'd make more sense to show a linear scale to the user and silently scale it logarithmically in the background.  Otherwise you'll have the issue a lot of TVs have where 5->10 is a huge difference in volume, but 25->30 is barely noticeable

Comment: This was my first thought as well. The slider can be really good at disallowing bad inputs

Answer (score 6):

Elementary factor seems to be fixing the error.

You need some intelligent code that will loop after the collection from * and if it encounters a hole, enter a value less than (index - 1) and greater than (index + 1).

Also:

1. **Dropdown with 50 options** is too mundane(but it's possible to implement search inside)

   [image]
2. **DatePicker** - sounds reasonably, 2 interactions to select a number, then all available immediately.

**Steppers** in this case, they intuitively don't seem like good options.

---

You can also use a simple input. Which, if you enter *, will take the value of the nearest number.

[image]

Comment: "You need some intelligent code that will loop after the collection from * and if it encounters a hole, enter a value less than (index - 1) and greater than (index + 1)." – I can't figure out what you're saying here. It sounds like you're saying that if the user selects an illegal value, the code should search for the *next* invalid value, but that doesn't seem like it would accomplish anything. Also, "less than (index - 1) and greater than (index + 1)" is impossible; maybe there was a typo there?

Comment: Thank's You wake me from letarg.
maybe I conveyed my thoughts in a somewhat chaotic way.

When iterating a collection (e.g. 10 elements) (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) in this case the index changes sequentially (from 1 to 2 to 3 to 4) let's assume that 5 is missing. The algorithm should capture this and write a value less than 6 and greater than 4, then greater than (5-1) and less than (5+1) - the only natural number satisfying this equation is - 5.

Comment: You're math expert  - if I make a mistake, which is possible - I would be grateful for improvement

Comment: FWIW, not possible to search a drop down in iPhone or iPad unless a keyboard is connected.

Answer (score 1):

If you can combine a normal number input with a drop down menu that greys out invalid number, and centers on the number entered, with up and down arrows that go to the next valid number, that strikes me as the most intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

The user should not be bothered with your historical reasons for limitations.

Prepare a mapping between valid values and consecutive numbers, e.g.:

```
Id:          1, 2, 3, 4,    5,    6,     7,     8,  9, 10
Valid value: 1, 2, 3, 4, *, 6, *, 8, *, 12, *, 16, 17, 18
```

and present the Id's to the user only ("pick a number between 1 and 50"). Behind the screens the chosen value must be mapped to the valid setting. And when you want to present the current setting to the user, perform the reverse mapping.

I don't know the complete structure of your system, I suppose however that you may run into ambiguity with support when the users start to report their settings. Either make the support department aware of the mapping or automate the problem reports where the mapping will be effected.

---

**EDIT:**

Should "some arbitrary value" (as named in one of the comments) is putting the OP off, present a slider with range from 1 to ~50 (without naming any values on it, only "min" and "max"), read the value and map it again with the mapping of the valid values.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work most of the time. This isn't a magic trick, you can't just ask the user to pick a number with no other information. The user needs to know what the number means in order to choose the correct value, which means entering the actual value, not some arbitrary value that maps to what they actually need behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm not sure this comment applies to my answer - the OP didn't give any context either on their "integer percentage value, from 1-100". In this case it will be a number between 1 and ~50 (as the OP indicates there are ~50 valid values).

Answer (score 0):

On first wrong input give a error message  and ask user to use the tooltip. Which shows valid and invalid numbers (invalid greyed out)